# Angular build for production

Tags: javascript, angular

I am fairly new to Angular, I am currently trying to work out how to serve only the necessary files to my deployment server.

Ideally, I wouldn't want to include the angular library in my project repo. Instead, I would like to install in the build process.

Like I said this is fairly new to me so am not entirely sure whether this is achievable or not?

Answer (score 1):

Angular 2 will be a dependancy of your project. Concretely you will have some javascript files added at installation (`npm install`) in your `ROOT/node_module` directory.

They will not be include in your NPM repo if you add a root file in your project named `.npmignore` with at least this content :

```
node_modules
```

You can do the same for your GIT repository and a file named `.gitignore` with at least this content :

```
node_modules/
```

Comment: What i was thinking is to have angular-cli installed on the build server and create new project in deployment then bring in my repo once a new project has been created

Comment: OK, for this usage, I think angular-cli-tolls templates are most appropriate https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-tools. Perso I prefer Yeoman that allowed you to make something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angular2